# .net identityuser problems with entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, identity

When we start a normal MVC project it comes with Identity.I have some models like Post.cs and Comment.cs

One to many relationship between post and comment

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Baslik { get; set; }
    public string Icerik { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Icerik { get; set; }
    public int PostId {get;set;}

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

`IdentityModel.cs` We have nothing in here but when i click with ctrl on IdentityUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}

public class IdentityUser : IUser
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Still weird to me for realationship and i clicked with ctrl on IUser

```
// Summary:
//     Minimal interface for a user with a string user key
public interface IUser
{
    // Summary:
    //     Unique key for the user
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The unique key for the user
    string Id { get; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing? I just want a relationship user-comment and user-post like between `Post` and `Comment` models.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: Question is There are so many classes in identity model like = ApplicationUser,IdentityUser, IUser which one should i use for relationships between user-comment and user-post ?